# Unresolved reference: runApplication on Kotlin

Tags: spring, maven, kotlin

When Im trying to import Spring kotlin archieve I have:

Unresolve reference: runApplication

The code is:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class RestapiApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<RestapiApplication>(*args)
```

Im still learning, so any help and advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like broken dependencies in your setup. This is impossible to answer without seeing the maven that pulls in these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem after trying second answer from here: https://stackguides.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij

1. gradle clean build
2. Project Structure -> {Select Module} -> Kotlin.

In Project structure->Modules I have 2 main modules and 2 test modules. I delete excessed modules and all is workes now.

Comment: Thanks!! 6 months later my answer haha but really thanks